# Ant include external project

Tags: java, ant, build

I have 3 projects open in my Eclipse and 2 of them are dependencies for the main one.  I also have a custom build script ( made by someone else ) that I use to build my project.  I would like for the build.xml file be able to include the external source files from the other projects.  I have tried something like this

```
    <path id="build.class.path">
        <fileset dir="${project-root}/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib" />
        <pathelement path="${classes-folder}" />
        <pathelement path="E:\EclipseWorkspace\workspace\clear4-runtime-core\src" />
    </path>
```

But no luck.  I must admit my ANT and build.xml skills are low to nonexistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're adding classpath elements, not source elements.

You'd need to modify where the `javac` task gets its sources from. See the [javac task docs](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html) for more details, particularly anything relating to the `sourcepath` or `sourcepathref` attributes, or the `src` elements.

This said, please don't hardcode any values like this into the build file as it ties it to a specific directory hierarchy. Provide a properties file that lets each dev assign their own values.

Comment: I can't thank you enough Dave.  That was it.  For anyone else, in my build.properties file I added an entry such as stacksource and set it to where the project to include was "${basedir}/stacksource".  Then in my build script at the javac   node of importance I changed the srcdir argument to be equal to "{project-root}/src${path.separator}${stacksource}/src". After actually find the right javac node it ran like a champ.  I don't mind learning new technologies, but the ones concerning Java seem to be overwhelming and love to throw archaic errors.

Comment: No sweat :) Remember to accept answers today solve your problem! And yep, deciphering what went wrong can be... challenging at times.